# JAVA ECLIPSE: Image coupled to a label is not loading

Tags: java, image, swing, loading

Does anyone know why my image is not loading? I tried many things and so far nothing, first of all the folder "IMGFiles" is already like Source Folder.

```
    package Main;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JFrame {

    public Menu()
    {
        ImageIcon imagem = new ImageIcon(Menu.class.getResource("/LiturgisGame/IMGFiles/LiturrgisLogoLoad.png"));
        JLabel logo = new JLabel();
        logo.setIcon(imagem);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new Menu();
        JFrame janela = new JFrame();
        janela.setSize(816, 419);
        janela.setUndecorated(true);
        janela.setVisible(true);
        janela.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using macOS, right?

Comment: No, is it Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using UNIX (for the shape of the path you are using).
Here is an approach for you:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.apple.eawt.Application;

public class Menu extends JFrame {

    public Menu(){ }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(new ImageIcon("/LiturgisGame/IMGFiles/LiturrgisLogoLoad.png").getImage());

        //new Menu();
        JFrame janela = new JFrame();
        janela.setSize(816, 419);
        janela.setUndecorated(true);
        janela.setVisible(true);
        janela.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: No, isn't, is it Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you prepare the JLabel inside Menu constructor and you do not initiate any instance of Menu class. Also, you do not add the JLabel into the frame (content pane).

Check this sample:

```
public class Menu extends JFrame {

    public Menu()
    {
        ImageIcon imagem = new ImageIcon(Menu.class.getResource("/LiturgisGame/IMGFiles/LiturrgisLogoLoad.png"));
        JLabel logo = new JLabel();
        logo.setIcon(imagem);
        setSize(816, 419);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().add(logo); //Add the label to the content pane
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            new Menu().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understood, what I do not understand, is that when I'm instantiating the Menu class when compiling return NullPointerException as shown in the image, with error in some lines: https://imgur.com/OMj5tYs

Comment: The folders LiturgisGame/IMGFiles doesn’t exists in the context, as IMGFiles is a source folder, it’s content is added to the build. You have to write "/LiturrgisLogoLoad.png" to access your file.

Comment: Test with a web resource: `URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");
  ImageIcon imagem = new ImageIcon(url);` if this is working fix you paths.